# Как поменять цвет анимированого Progress Bar'a?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

Всем привет!

Я установил анимированый [Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#animated) с сайта jQuery UI к себе на сайт, используя такой простой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
                            value: 35
                    });
            });
            </script>
<div id="progressbar">  </div>
```

Как можно изменить цвет самого прогресс бара? Плюс еще была идея сделать так - от 0% до 20% - цвет красный, от 20% до 70% желтый цвет, от 70% до 100% использовать зеленый цвет. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь..

Comment: А как сделать что бы он двигался во время загрузки файла. Что бы показывал сколько файла загружено в данный момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри здесь, что то похожее что ты описываешь [Progress Bar](http://www.bram.us/demo/projects/jsprogressbarhandler/)

Comment: Слушайте, подскажите мне пожалуйста как сделать что бы при загрузке файла этот `value` двигался ???

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день!
Надо обрабатывать `progresschange`. Там же, на сайте который указали в посте, есть вкладка Event, посмотрите примеры там. Так же, как вариант, можно покопаться в стилях.
**UPD:** А по поводу разноцветного прогрессбара, можно попробовать нарисовать 3 картинки с тремя цветами, и заменить ею стандартный цвет, по мере "прогресса" или уже копаться в исходниках виджета `progressBar`.